# Is there a way to 'Save HAR with content' in Chrome with a hotkey shortcut?

Tags: python, google-chrome, har

I would like to periodically save HAR with content on a website. I tried using headless chrome, but I found out that if I'm using headless chrome, there's only a way to do this with using browsermob-proxy. Using a proxy gives me problems, because somehow it's constantly sending IO socket requests, status code 101, because I'm using a proxy. I don't really know if this is solvable? If someone is able to help me on this, that's welcome too.

So now I'm trying to save har with content in normal chrome. Is there a way I can set a hotkey / shortcut? I tried Shortkeys chrome extension, but it doesn't give an option for the save HAR.